# Modify regex to more selective

Tags: asp.net, regex, iis

Using urlrewriting on a website that also has a blog, however I have found an issue with conflicting rules.

I think can be resolved by simply modifying the regex in the offending rule to eliminate the blog pages, but I've not yet been able to get it to work.

Here's the issue that's causing the problem:

```
www.mysite.com <== my site
www.mysite.com/blog/... <== root of blog
```

At the moment, the regex is simply `"(.*)/$"`, which is actionable on all pages.

However, it obviously picks up the blog pages. The blog has a slightly different setup which causes issues when I apply the rule, so I'm looking to be able to select the main site pages, but not anything that has the `/blog/` directory in its structure.

Anyone help me convert the regex pattern to exclude what I need - I've tried so many permutations - its now causing issues, as our SEO is broken, and its very difficult to test over on the live system.

Comment: You can do that with a [negative lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html). Beware that not all regex parsers support lookaheads/behinds

Comment: @anubhava - the issue is I have a rule in the web.config file that removes the trailing slash from aurl, however on the website, the Wordpress logic tries to add it back. I don't want to change the WP setting because it will cause more hassle (and loss of results), so trying to work around it.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web.config) tells me that `web.config` files are those used by ASP.NET. Is that right? If so, please add a tag to your question, as this is a relevant detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elegance of the regex used depends on the power of the regex engine which in turn depends on the environment your regex is used in.

***Basic***

Works with any engine since it only uses basic operators.
Write

```
^www.mysite.com($|/$|(/([^b]|b[^l]|bl[^o]|blo[^g]|blog[^/])).*)/$
```

or for general domains (not advisable imho)

```
^[^/]+($|/$|(/([^b]|b[^l]|bl[^o]|blo[^g]|blog[^/])).*)/$
```

***Negative Lookahead***

Patterns may be specified contingent on non-occurrence of entire strings after a particular position within a match.

```
^(www.mysite.com(?!/blog/).*)$
```

For more details on lookahead ( and the similar concept of lookbehind ) see [this part](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) of a [resource on regular expressions engines and the concepts behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info).

**Web Server URL Rewriting**

If the execution context is a URL rewrite module, you may exploit rule ordering, special processing directives and flags to simplify the regexen. Aside from peculiarities of the syntax, the general ideas of the samples should be implementable in any decent Url rewriting plugin.

***Microsoft URL Rewriting module for IIS***

(***Note***: The content of this section reflects MS documentation only.)

There is a [tutorial](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module) on how to specify Rewriting rules in IIS. As authoritative source for the available regex syntax,the [ECMA-262 standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) is given (basically that's JavaScript - so lookahead should be available).

Thus in the `web.config` configuration file, the rewrite section should look like:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Whatever description fits">
      <match url="^(www.mysite.com(?!/blog/).*)$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="example.com/whatever" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

***Apache mod_rewrite and compatible***

The following sample addresses your problem for Apache 2.4/mod_rewrite and [IIS/IIS-Mod-Rewrite](http://www.micronovae.com/ModRewrite/ModRewrite.html).

(***Note***: The website of the IIS plugin claims to be 100% mod_rewrite compatible. I do not know whether that claim is correct.):

```
RewriteRule ^(www.mysite.com/blog/.*)$ $0 [S=1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ...
```

where `...` represents the rewritten url plus any applicable flags. The first rule leaves a matched blog url unchanged and due to the skip flag (`[S=1]`) ignores the next rewriting rule.

You might also wish to look at the `END`flag and the `RewriteCond` directive.

Reference: Apache Docs ( [Apache httpd 2.4: mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) )

Comment: I'm using Asp.Net, so it's a Windows/IIS environment.

Comment: Why all the partial variants - is it not possible to ignore /blog/ as a whole word entity?

Comment: Depends on your execution environment. If the regex engine supports negative lookahead, it is easy. The exec env might provide operational semantics that help you (ordered rules, processing flags like in the Apache example). With basic regex you are confined to the given solution since they only come with negation of characters but not strings.

Comment: collapsar - thanks for your thorough answer. It not only resolves my IIS specifc issue, but will also help others looking for similar answers.